What's the proper way to enable SQLite WAL mode with Kotlin's Exposed?
I tried this, using setupConnection, got it from a github issue:
import org.jetbrains.exposed.sql.Database
import org.sqlite.SQLiteConfig

Database.connect(
    "jdbc:sqlite:$dbPath",
    driver = "org.sqlite.JDBC",
    setupConnection = {
        SQLiteConfig().apply {
            setJournalMode(SQLiteConfig.JournalMode.WAL)
            setSynchronous(SQLiteConfig.SynchronousMode.FULL)
        }
    })

but there is no *-wal or *-shm files, and running PRAGMA journal_mode returns delete, which is the default mode.
Doing this:
transaction { 
    exec("PRAGMA journal_mode = WAL;")
    exec("PRAGMA synchronous = FULL;")
}

returns cannot change into wal mode from within a transaction.
So I'm enabling it like this now:
import java.sql.DriverManager

DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:$dbPath").use { conn ->
    conn.createStatement().use { stmt ->
        stmt.executeUpdate("PRAGMA journal_mode = WAL;")
        stmt.executeUpdate("PRAGMA synchronous = FULL;")
    }
}

but is there an idiomatic way to enable WAL mode using just the exposed library?
